# Connecting Flight in Zurich—is 1.25 Hrs. Enough Time for a Layover (Arriving from Thessaloniki, Departing for Denver)?

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, short-connections, zurich, zrh

My son would land in Zurich at 11:50 am on a Wed. (on a Swiss Air flight from Thessaloniki) and would connect to a 1:05 flight to Denver (via Edelweiss), traveling on a U.S. passport.
He won't have any checked or carry-on bags, just a backpack.
Will he need to clear Customs and go through Passport control?
How long a trek would it be from one gate to the other?
Does this sound like a feasible transfer time, or does it sound like he might well miss his connection?

Comment: Just being a pain in the neck: your son is unlikely to fly on Swissair, since the company went bankrupt in 2002 ( https://www.swissair.com/ch/de# ) .  But Swiss is operating nowadays :)

Comment: Is it a single ticket? If so, the airline will re-book him if he misses it, as long as he walks in the direction at a reasonably brisk pace.

Comment: doesn't a bag that you carry with you qualify as a "carry-on"?

Answer (score 1):

> Will he need to clear Customs and go through Passport control?

Yes, he'll need to go through passport control, since he'll be exiting the Schengen area in Zurich. He won't need to go through customs control if it is a connection (i.e.: both flights are on the same ticket).

> Does this sound like a feasible transfer time, or does it sound like he might well miss his connection?

Tight, but probably doable. If the flights are on separate tickets and reservations he might need to go out and check in and go back in again in ZRH, which may make it significantly riskier. But if it's the same ticket and reservation, he'll be checked in all the way through to Denver from Greece, and if he misses the connection the airline will take care of rebooking him.

Answer (score 1):

Switzerland is member of the Schengen area, your son will need to go through the exit passport control, so the schedule is tight, but doable.

Walking distance is at teh very maximum 20 minutes (the airport is quite compact), there is a 5-10 minutes ride in a small train shuttle to connect from the main terminal to the non-Schengen flights terminal ... so if the passport control takes 20 minutes (unlikely), your son will still make it to the boarding gate (right) on time.

Comment: It's not "main terminal vs. long-haul flights terminal". It's Schengen terminal vs. non-Schengen terminal. Flights to non-Schengen destinations always depart from the latter, and their passengers must use the underground people mover, even if the flight is not long-haul. E.g. Zurich to London is quite short, but still outside of Schengen...

Comment: @Johnnyjanko  thanks